# Kotlin Android - Notification not appearing as heads up

Tags: android, kotlin

(My device is running Android 5.1.)

For an app I've making, I've created a type of notification class, with methods, etc., which make it easy to create notifications.

I've tried to configure it to use a 'heads-up' notification, although it has not been working for me. It just appears as a regular notification: maybe I have gotten something wrong?

Notification helper class and interface:

```
interface NotificationHelper {
        fun startNotification(title: String, text: String, priority: Int, smallIcon: Int)
    }
    
    class DefaultNotificationHelper(private val context: Context) : NotificationHelper {
        private val channelID = "channel_01"

        private fun registerNotificationManagerWithSystem(channel: NotificationChannel) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                (context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
        }

        private fun createNotificationChannel() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val notificationChannelInstance = NotificationChannel(channelID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).let {
                    it.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
                    it.setShowBadge(true)

                    registerNotificationManagerWithSystem(it)
                }
            }
        }

        private fun createNotificationInstance(title: String, text: String, priority: Int, smallIcon: Int): NotificationCompat.Builder {
            return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setPriority(priority)
                    .setDefaults(DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                    .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        }

        private fun notify(notificationCompat: NotificationCompat.Builder) {
            (context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).notify(1, notificationCompat.build())
        }

        override fun startNotification(title: String, text: String, priority: Int, smallIcon: Int) {
            createNotificationChannel()
            notify(createNotificationInstance(title, text, priority, smallIcon))
        }
    }
```

Implementation:

```
val notificationHelper = DefaultNotificationHelper(this)
        notificationHelper.startNotification("Hello", "Hello", NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH, R.drawable.fire_gradient)
```

This could be something related to my phone though.

### Edit

I've determined that it's just an issue with my phone, it doesn't matter how hard I try - it will never work. Don't get a Huawei Y6 Elite if you want to test heads-up notifications, it WON'T work no matter how hard you try.

Comment: have you tested it on any latest version maybe Andoird-8 or above ?

Comment: @ADM Heads up notifications were added in 5.0... My device is also a Huawei so maybe they don't have that feature. Anyways I cannot afford a new phone, and my computer can barely run the emulator...

Comment: @TomJoney how about trying it out on an emulator?

Comment: @Anatolii I will try this.

Comment: @Anatolii tested in emulator and also not working :(. Would love a solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Github project link, it has a custom heads-up notification code.
https://github.com/kavitamp/CustomHeadsUpNotification

I have tested it on Android 10 & it's working fine. Here's the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: It's amazing. So you have just implemented the code for this question ? It's an amazing work. Appreciated !

Comment: I had worked on this functionality before, so thought to share :)

Comment: I will check this out tomorrow. If I could give you a gold medal I would; for you are more-than-honorary of one. I respect you from the bottom of my heart... Thank you is not enough.

Comment: @Kavita_p it works on the emulator, but it doesn't seem to be working on my phone, on my phone is just displays as a regular one. It's most likely an issue with my phone... Thanks anyways.

Comment: Hi @TomJoney, I just came across https://github.com/SimenCodes/heads-up code related to heads-up notifications, he has mentioned some "Common Issues". You can check if this works on ur phone or not.